# How can I delete $scope object from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Is it possible to delete `$scope.contacts` object from the `service()` function ?

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);
module.service('ContactService', function() {
  //contacts array to hold list of all contacts
  this.delete = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    var confirmDelete = confirm("Do you really need to delete " + item.name + " ?");
    if (confirmDelete) {
      var curIndex = $scope.contacts.indexOf(item);
      $scope.contacts.splice(curIndex, 1);
    }
  }
});
module.controller('ContactController', function($scope, ContactService) {
  $scope.contacts = [{
    id: 0,
    'name': 'Viral',
    'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
    'phone': '123-2343-44'
  }];
  $scope.delete = function(id) {
    ContactService.delete(id);
    if ($scope.newcontact.id == id) $scope.newcontact = {};
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController" class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete(contact)">delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass controller's `$scope` to service ?

Comment: @Vineet I need to delete an object from `$scope.contacts`

Comment: I think what @Vineet is getting at is that your `$scope.contacts` is in the controller so why are you trying to delete it from a service? Your service doesn't have access to your scope. So just delete it in the controller.

Comment: Really, you would do your confirmation in your controller and remove it from the $scope.contacts in your controller. Your service would then remove it from your db, or wherever..you're mixing concerns here.

Comment: @Darren I am inspired from this tutorial http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/72vT5/light/

Comment: $scope is isolated to Controller and Service - so in ContactService $scope.contacts will be undefined since it's defined in  ContactController. You can fix this by injecting $scope.contacts from Controller to Service OR use $rootscope.contacts

Comment: Your $scope.contacts object should be defined in your service not your controller

Answer (score 1):

This would not make sense, as a service is a singleton (one exists per app), whereas you can have multiple controllers. If the service could get hold of a scope, how does it know it got the right one!

You could make this work by passing the `$scope` into the delete function, like

```
this.delete = function($scope, item)
```

and

```
ContactService.delete($scope, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Long answer: No, you can't, because a scopes are tied to controllers that in turn are tied to views, and services are view-independent (hence their name ;-)).

So, to cut a long story short: It's not possible to access a scope from within a service, because the service is responsible for multiple views (and scopes). You will never know which scope to use, because for a service there is no "ambient" or "current" scope.

If you actually want to to access the scope directly, hand it over to the service (as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31841823/1333873) by [Andy Newman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4166434/andy-newman)). But I'd not recommend this, because then the service acts on something it should not know about.

A better approach would be to think about messaging, so that the service lets all interested parties (i.e., controllers) know to do something on their scope.

Probably the best option is not to hold the data in the controller, but to put the data into the service, so that it's the service's responsibility to deal with the data and delete them when appropriate. Controllers then only need to tell the service what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send the $scope. Just send the contacts array:

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);
module.service('ContactService', function () {
//contacts array to hold list of all contacts
this.delete  = function (contacts, item) {
 var confirmDelete = confirm("Do you really need to delete " + item.name + " ?");
 if (!confirmDelete) {
  return;
 }

 var curIndex = contacts.indexOf(item);
 contacts.splice(curIndex, 1);
};
});
module.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService) {
$scope.contacts = [{
  id : 0,
  'name' : 'Viral',
  'email' : 'hello@gmail.com',
  'phone' : '123-2343-44'
 }
];
$scope.delete  = function (item) {
 var id = item.id;
 ContactService.delete ($scope.contacts, item);
 if ($scope.newcontact.id == id)
  $scope.newcontact = {};
}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController" class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete(contact)">delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `$scope` to a service is not the Angular way.

It's better to let the service manage your data (as mentioned in Golo's answer). Then you can also do `$http` request to keep your model/data in synch. with your backend.

Have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zrLmxrez/).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('contactService', function () {
        
    //contacts array to hold list of all contacts
    var service = {
        contacts: [{
            id: 0,
                'name': 'Viral',
                'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
                'phone': '123-2343-44'
        }, {
            id: 1,
                'name': 'John',
                'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
                'phone': '123-2343-44'
        }, {
            id: 2,
                'name': 'Jane',
                'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
                'phone': '123-2343-44'
        }],
        
        delete: function (item) {
            console.log(item);
            var itemIndex;
            var confirmDelete = confirm("Do you really need to delete " + item.name + " ?");
            if (confirmDelete) {
                angular.forEach(this.contacts, function(contact, index) {
                    if(item.id === contact.id) {
                        itemIndex = index;
                    }
                });

                this.contacts.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            }
        }
    };
    return service;
})
    .controller('contactController', function ($scope, contactService) {
    $scope.contacts = contactService.contacts;

    $scope.delete = function (contact) {
        contactService.delete(contact);
        //if ($scope.newcontact.id == id) $scope.newcontact = {};
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="contactController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">{{contact.name}}
            <button ng-click="delete(contact)">remove</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```